# I need to authenticate in NestJS without middleware

Tags: authentication, http-headers, nestjs

I have url, this url needs authentication with username and password. On PHP I made it with curl_setopt(CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . $password), I can't find any solution how to set password and username on same link on NestJS.

```
import { Injectable, Scope, HttpService } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ImporterService } from '../importer.service';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class Supplier extends ImporterService {
supplierName = 'supplierName';
fileDownload: boolean = false;
username = 'username;
password = 'password';


async parse() {
await this.checkSupplierExist(this.supplierName);
return this.httpService
  .get(
    'https://www.link.com/restful/export/api/products.xml?acceptedlocales=en_US&addtags=true',
  )
  .pipe( map(response => console.log(response)));
 }
}
```

this response sends 401, cause it needs authentication. I cannot figure out how to set username or  password. Can anyone help?

Comment: Nice help, thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

From me I have a Config service which handles http calls, looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
    private readonly envConfig: { [key: string]: string };
    private servers: Object = {};

    constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {
        this.envConfig = {
            PORT: process.env.PORT,
            MONGODB_URI: process.env.MONGODB_URI,
            MONGODB_SESSION_URI: process.env.MONGODB_SESSION_URI,
            SESSION_SECRET: process.env.SESSION_SECRET
        };

        const externals = JSON.parse(process.env.EXTERNALS);
        for (const lang in externals) {
            this.servers[lang] = externals[lang];
        }
    }

    get(key: string): string {
        return this.envConfig[key];
    }

    getServer(lang: string, method: string, url: string, headers: Object, params?: Object, data?: Object) {
        const config = { baseURL: this.servers[lang], url, headers, method, data, params };
        return this.httpService.request(config).toPromise();
    }
}
```

As you can see in the getServer method, you can add headers as well.
I hope this is what you're looking for